# ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 3, python2 pickle can not load the file dumped by python 3 pickle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pickle, valueerror

I use pickle to dump a file on python 3, and I use pickle to load the file on python 2, the ValueError appears.

So, python 2 pickle can not load the file dumped by python 3 pickle?

If I want it? How to do?

Comment: If you are stuck with already-written pickled files, then check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571063/i-have-pickled-files-using-protocol-3-in-python3-and-now-i-need-to-unpickle-the/34571081#34571081

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You should write the pickled data with a lower protocol number in Python 3. Python 3 introduced a new protocol with the number `3` (and uses it as default), so switch back to a value of `2` which can be read by Python 2.

Check the `protocol`parameter in [`pickle.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump). Your resulting code will look like this.

```
pickle.dump(your_object, your_file, protocol=2)
```

There is no `protocol`parameter in [`pickle.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load) because `pickle` can determine the protocol from the file.

Answer (score 57):

Pickle uses different `protocols` to convert your data to a binary stream.

- In python 2 there are [3 different protocols](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format) (`0`, `1`, `2`) and the default is `0`.
- In python 3 there are [5 different protocols](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format) (`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`) and the default is `3`.

You must specify in python 3 a protocol lower than `3` in order to be able to load the data in python 2. You can specify the `protocol` parameter when invoking [`pickle.dump`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump).

Comment: Just for future reference, apparently there's a protocol `5` that was introduced in Python 3.8 as well which is not compatible with earlier versions.

Comment: re: protocol 5
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0574/