# How to add dictionary values in python numpy array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to create numpy array and data keys are `positions`, `metadata`. Its output should be like below

```
#sample output
['positions', metadata] #data keys when I print file_name.keys()
{'num_pos': 10, 'keypoints': [[4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12], [1, 2, 3, 13, 14, 15]]} #values of metadata in dictionary when I print file_name['metadata']
```

I want output same as above. Below is my python code to get required npz file.

```
#code sample
positions = [] #this step is working and values are saved in npz file, so I'm just skipping this step, my problem is in metadata key which is given below
metadata = {
'num_pos': 10,
'keypoints': [[4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12], [1, 2, 3, 13, 14, 15]]
}

positions = np.array(positions).astype(np.float32)
np.savez_compressed('file_name.npz', position=positions, metadata=metadata)
```

With above code I can get npz file having values of `positions` but not values of `metadata`. When I print `file_name.keys()` then output is `['positions', 'metadata']` which is ok but when I print `file_name['metadata']` I'm getting following error.

```
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 3
```

Looking for valuable suggestions

Comment: You example doesn't give me the error you're reporting. You're currently missing a comma after your filename in the save call, but that raises a SyntaxError. Could you tweak your example to reproduce the error?

Comment: I just edit it. I got the point that its problem is due to different protocols in Python 3 and 2. I'm saving npz file in Python 3 but I need to use it in Python 2 project. I think this is the main problem. I got this [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843698/valueerror-unsupported-pickle-protocol-3-python2-pickle-can-not-load-the-file) but its for pickle not for npz and I'm unable to find right protocol for numpy array to save npz file in Python 3 that can also be used in Python 2. Could you help me regarding this problem?